# How to supply list of dependencies to ejbdeploy.bat using Gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have recently started using Gradle(1.12) to build our application components and the first place we have started is by doing EJB Deploy. This is what we are trying to achieve:

1. compile a sourceSet which is located at project directory **/ejbModule** ( This consists of the java classes and META-INF folder which contains ejb-jar.xml and other websphere related xml's.
2. Create a jar which will contain the above package and resources
3. run ejbdeploy.bat located at %WAS_HOME%\bin which takes input as jar created in step 2 which will create stubs / skeletons and re-package the jar at a different directory.

Now this is my gradle build file

```
def wasHome = 'C:/Data/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer'
def internalClasses = 'C:/GoldCopy1/Workspace/chimessharedlib'
def appPath = 'C:/GoldCopy1/Workspace/IEApp'

apply plugin:'java'

repositories {

flatDir {
   dirs wasHome + '/lib'
   dirs internalClasses
   dirs appPath
  }
}

dependencies {

compile name : 'j2ee'
compile name : 'commons-lang-2.3'
compile name : 'FW'
compile name : 'Common'
compile name : 'DA'
compile name : 'ST'
}

sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDir '/ejbModule'
    }
    resources {
        srcDir '/ejbModule'
    }
  }
}

task runEJBDeploy (type:Exec) {
commandLine wasHome + '/bin/ejbdeploy.bat', '/C'

def inputJar = "" + libsDir + File.separator + 'AR.jar';
println inputJar;
def argsList = [inputJar, "C:\\tpp" , "C:\\tpp\\deploy\\AR.jar" , "-complianceLevel", "5.0"]
args = argsList;
}
```

So by running the *runEJBDeploy* task above, I want to generate a command like below:

```
ejbdeploy.bat -cp "C:\tpp\FW.jar;C:\tpp\DA.jar;C:\tpp\Common.jar" C:\tpp\AR.jar C:\tpp C:\tpp\deployed\AR.jar -complianceLevel 5.0
```

So since FW, DA and Common are already provided in the dependencies { } section of the build.gradle file, is there a way to use those dependencies for appending it after "-cp  " and then run the command?

I am very new to gradle so please also point out any other wrong approach taken which should be improved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A Windows batch script cannot be executed directly. Instead you'll have to execute `cmd /C batchScriptPath`. Either you set `commandLine`, or both `executable` and `args`. (The former is a combination of the latter.) The class path arg can be generated with `configurations.compile.asPath`.

Comment: Peter I am able to execute the batch file with the build file I provided above and the ejbdeploy tasks run successfully, however since it does not contain the dependencies, it fails saying the general ClassNotFoundException or NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Peter, adding configurations.compile.asPath did the trick. I was able to execute the ejbDeploy and generate the stubs. Thanks!